# Apache POI cannot get horizontally merged cells in .doc file

Tags: java, api, apache-poi, document, doc

I have a .doc file that contains a table.

When I tried to use `.isVerticallyMerged()` to check if a table cell is vertically merged, it works perfectly but when I try to use `.isMerged()` to check if a cell is horizontally merged, it returns false even on horizontally merged cells.

Is this the correct way to check for horizontally merged cells?